# image intervention Image source not readable Laravel

Tags: laravel, image, intervention

I try to make a image from a image stored on Digital Ocean spaces.
When i do `file_get_contents($urlToImage)` it says `Image source not readable`

```
public function getFormats()
{

    $image = Storage::disk('dospace')->url($this->image);

    //dd($image);

    $imageContent = file_get_contents(Storage::disk('dospace')->url($this->image));

    $width = Image::make($imageContent)->width();

    $height = Image::make($imageContent)->height();

    $sizes = [

        'width' => $width,
        'height' => $height

    ];

    return $sizes;

}
```

Does someone know what the problem is?

Comment: Is there a reason you are accessing the file through URL rather than natively copying/moving the file? It looks like you are using your own Digital Ocean storage disk, correct? If so, you should be able to use the File facade to manipulate the file natively, without having to call the URL

Comment: Yes correct, its my own storage disk but its a remote disk. So you mean first move the file to your server and then manipulate the image on the server. Or can i access the file in a different wey?

Comment: I don't know all the details about the setup but it could have to do with file permissions on accessing the file through URL method in DO. So if you have access to move the file using the Storage and File facades and then manipulate locally, it should solve your problem by eliminating any permissions issues or problems loading a remote file related to the way the DO space is setup. Try doing that and see if you can get it to work, and then you would know that the problem is with the way you are trying to load the image, and not with the image itself or with your use of the Image facade.

Comment: is `allow_url_fopen` directive activated in your php.ini ?

Comment: your  url must not have space ..